# Solve the given limit

Tags: integration, limits

Find the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\sin^2\frac rn$$

My approach to solve this question so far has been,

if  $ i = 1, 2, 3, ..., n $ . The definite integral of $ f $ on the interval $ [a, b] $ can now be alternatively defined by 
$ \displaystyle{ \int^{b}_{a} f(x) \, dx}
= \displaystyle{ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(c_{i}) \Delta x
_{i} } $ .

Hence the limit will basically be the definite  integral of $\sin^2(r/x)$ from $1$ to $n$. Is there right approach and if it is, is this the right reasoning to it or is there any other supporting explanation that can be made to back it up?

Comment: It's the right approach but you have the wrong limits of integration. You also have the wrong integrand.

Comment: Since it's from 1 to infinity, I'm not very sure what the limit should be

Comment: Look in your book for an example of a Riemann sum, and match the details to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

The limit $= \int_{0}^1 \sin^2(x) dx$

Comment: Hi Fred! Isn't there a constant of 1/n and how exactly did you get the limit as 0-1?

Comment: Use the partition $\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},..., \frac{n}{n} \}$ of $[0,1]$.

Comment: What about the constant of 1/n outside?

Comment: @GaryAndrews30: that is $\Delta x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us go for the explicit way. Since $\sin^2\theta=\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left(\frac{2k}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{\sin(1)}{2}\cdot\left[\cos(1)\cot\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sin(1)\right] $$
hence by dividing both sides by $n$ and considering the limit as $n\to +\infty$
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sin(1)\cos(1)}{2} = \color{red}{\frac{2-\sin2}{4}}.$$
Since $\sin^2(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$, by Riemann sums
$$ \frac{2-\sin(2)}{4}=\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2\left(\frac{k}{n}\right).$$